# A question about Limits rules

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

If we know all the following results in the region
$0< t< π$:

If  $t\neq t_0$ in the region
$0< t< π$

$$\lim_{u\to \infty} {\int_{1}^{u} f(x,t)dx}\neq0  $$
$$\lim_{u\to \infty} {\int_{1}^{u} g(x,t)dx}\neq0 $$

If  $t= t_0$ in the region
$0< t< π$
$$\lim_{u\to \infty} {\int_{1}^{u} f(x,t_0)dx}=0 $$
$$\lim_{u\to \infty} {\int_{1}^{u} g(x,t_0)dx}=0 $$

Also, we have the following equation if $t\neq t_0$:

$$\tag{1}\frac {\lim_{u\to \infty} {\int_{1}^{u} f(x,t)dx}}{\lim_{u\to \infty} {\int_{1}^{u} g(x,t)dx}}=\sin(t)$$

**Now, can we follow below two steps?** -
**Is there any mistake which I have made ?**

$$\tag{2}\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac {{\int_{1}^{u} f(x,t)dx}}{ {\int_{1}^{u} g(x,t)dx}}=\sin(t)$$

Then, we can handle the above equation with $t_0$ as below:

$$\tag{3}\lim_{u\to \infty}\frac {{\int_{1}^{u} f(x,t_0)dx}}{ {\int_{1}^{u} g(x,t_0)dx}}=\sin(t_0)$$

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you assume that for a certain $t_0\in(0,\pi)$ and $t_*\in(0,\pi)$ with $t_*\neq t_0$ your conclussions is possible?

I do not belive so to be the truth, for example let $f(x,t) = sin^2(t_*)(t-t_0)e^{-(x-1)}$ and $g(x,t) = sin(t_*)(t-t_0)e^{-(x-1)}$ and you have a contradiction.

Comment: Noticed I made a misstake in my counter example I think it is fixed now. Yes you can obtain equation 2 from what you stated, the inverse is though not possible. Equation 3 can not be obtained from 1 though as showed by my counter example.

Comment: Still, I have a problem with your example. Please show it more clearly with operation? Also you wrote $sin(t_*)^2$  .  Or do you want to write it as  $sin^2(t_*)$.   Do you say that we can not obtain  Equation  $3$ from Equation $2$.

Comment: Yes, sorry for a delay, I fixed a problem I saw, but as defined now it works. With functions defined as above we have primitive functions $F(u,t) = sin^2(t_*)(t-t_0)(1-e^{-(x-1)})$ and $G(u,t) = sin(t_*)(t-t_0)(1-e^{-(x-1)})$. Let $u\rightarrow \infty$ and we have $F(t) = sin^2(t_*)(t-t_0)$ and $G(t) = sin(t_*)(t-t_0)$ which fufills the first 4 equations for $t_*\neq \frac{\pi}{2}$. For equation 4-5 we also have an equality but for equation 6 we have $\frac{F(t_0)}{G(t_0)}=sin(t_*)$. Hope this explains the counterexample well and sorry again for the delay.

Comment: Dear Oskar, thank you . It is enough, thank you.  It is certain that we can not understand each other.  Let us wait some new comment from the other friends: of course if it come.